# How to process dataframe without creating NaN's everywhere?

Tags: python, excel, where-clause

I have a set of columns that contain dates (imported from Excel file), and I need to process them as follows:

If a cell in one of those columns is blank, set another column to 1, else that column is 0.  This allows me to sum all the 1's and show that those items are missing.

This is how I am doing that at present:

```
df_combined['CDR_Form_notfound'] = np.where(df_combined['CDR-Form'].mask(df_combined['CDR-Form'].str.len()==0).isnull(),1,0)
```

A problem I am having is that I have to format those columns so that A) dates are trimmed to show only the day/month/year and B) some of the columns have a value of "see notes" in them, instead of being a date or blank.  That "see notes" is essential to properly accounting for missing items, it has to be there to keep the cell from flagging as empty and the item counting as missing (adding to the 'blank cells' count).  The actual problem is that if I run this code before the .isnull code above, evry blank becomes a NaN or a nan or a NaT, and then NOTHING flags as null/missing.

This is the code I am using to trim the date strings and change the "see notes" to a string...because otherwise it just ends up blank in the output.

```
for c in df_combined[dateColumns]:
        df_combined[c] = df_combined[c].astype(str) # uncomment this if columns change from dtype=str 
        df_combined[c] = np.where(df_combined[c].str.contains("20"), df_combined[c].str[:10], df_combined[c])
        df_combined[c] = np.where(df_combined[c].str.contains("see notes"), df_combined[c].str, df_combined[c])
```

I think my problem might have something to do with the dtypes of the columns.  When I run print(df.dtypes), every column shows as 'object', except for one I specifically set to int using this:

```
df_combined['Num'] = df_combined['Num'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x == x else "")
```

Comment: Well, you either have dates or you have objects in a column. Have you thought about translating "see notes" to a fake date, like 1970-01-01? Because now you try to mix strings, dates and NaNs. I would rather mix dates and NaNs. Because that is what pandas supports.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count NaNs?
If yes, you can just do:

```
len(df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()])
```

I see that you mention "blank" because it is comming from excel, so what you could do is to transform these blanks into nan before running the command above using:

```
df['CDR-Form'].replace('', np.NaN,inplace=True)
```

Comment: This ended up working for me.  
  
`for c in df_combined[dateColumns]:
        df_combined[c] = df_combined[c].astype(str)
        df_combined[c] = np.where(df_combined[c].str.contains("20"), df_combined[c].str[:10], df_combined[c])`